# Reset Interval Timer Don't Work! What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I wan't to make script timer and reset button. when i click reset then timer will be reseted and running again. i'm new in javascript so it's hard for me.

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="item html">
    <h2>60</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
    <button type="butoton" id="previous">
    Reset
    </button>
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
var time = 1;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 59;
var interval;

var timer = function() { 
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('h2').text(i);
    if (i == time) {    
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    i--;  
  }, 1000);
};


$('#previous').click(function(){
    //go back to previous slide and reset time
   clearInterval(interval);
   timer()
});
```

Here's my full code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/606/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined `interval` outside of the function, you don't need to create new `var interval` in the function.

Just remove the `var` inside `timer` function. Check   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/611/)

```
var timer = function() { 
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('h2').text(i);
        if (i == time) {    
      clearInterval(interval);
            return;
    }
    
    i--;  
}, 1000);
};
```

Also if you would like timer to start from 60 again you should define new time to `i`. Because inside the `timer` function you are decrementing value of `i`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    timer()
});

$('#previous').click(function(){
    //go back to previous slide and reset time
   i=59
   clearInterval(interval);
   timer()
});
```

Comment: Check the answer and fiddle again, i updated to run the timer when document ready

Answer (score 0):

Your redefining `interval` in the function scope. Hence js will treat it as a separate variable rather re-using the one defined in the previous scope/execution context. Just remove the `var` keyword in the function...

```
var timer = function() { 
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('h2').text(i);
        if (i == time) {    
          clearInterval(interval);
          return;
        }
        i--;  
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: When you reset the timer, reset the value of `i` too

Answer (score 0):

There were two mistake in your code.
1. interval defined twice.
2. Forgot to reset time to 59 while reseting

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/609/

Updated JS code is

```
var time = 1;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 59;
var interval;

var timer = function() { 
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('h2').text(i);
        if (i == time) {    
      clearInterval(interval);
            return;
    }

    i--;  
}, 1000);
};


$('#previous').click(function(){
    //go back to previous slide and reset time
   clearInterval(interval);
   i=59;
   timer()
});
```

Comment: it's work but the problem is the timer not auto running